# Retrieve exact image size using twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have seen examples on retrieving images and their sizes but most give size variation (s) provided  by Twitter.

One part of JSON source from twitter call has:

```
"media":[{"display_url":"pic.twitter.com/JLYolPIqvN","indices":[71,94],"sizes":{"small":{"w":340,"h":227,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":980,"h":653,"resize":"fit"},"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":600,"h":400,"resize":"fit"}}
```

This is what seems to be used in examples I have seen. But this doesn't give exact image size but available variations.

is it possible to get exact image size? e.g. if i wanted to only use `medium image` how do I get that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can to append the size to the end of the image URL.

For example, let's take this Tweet - https://twitter.com/RGB_Colours/status/699202254407147520

If we look at the entities, we will see the `media_url_https` which contains the URl of the image:

```
media": [
      {
        "id": 699202254352621600,
        "id_str": "699202254352621568",
        "indices": [
          27,
          50
        ],
        "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/CbQQvuzXIAA3cjd.png",
        "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CbQQvuzXIAA3cjd.png",
        "url": "https://t.co/FHNjU2c0SB",
        "display_url": "pic.twitter.com/FHNjU2c0SB",
        "expanded_url": "http://twitter.com/RGB_Colours/status/699202254407147520/photo/1",
```

The image URL is `https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CbQQvuzXIAA3cjd.png` - so we can append `:thumb`, `:small`, `:medium`, `:large` to it:

- https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CbQQvuzXIAA3cjd.png:thumb
- https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CbQQvuzXIAA3cjd.png:small
- https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CbQQvuzXIAA3cjd.png:medium
- https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CbQQvuzXIAA3cjd.png:large

You can also use the (undocumented) parameter `:orig` which will give you the original size of the image.  This may or may not be larger than `:large`

- https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CbQQvuzXIAA3cjd.png:orig

Comment: Okay. This works. It will help if it's documented somewhere.

Comment: Sadly the Twitter documentation is very sparse. Please mark the answer as solved if I have been helpful.

Comment: @TerenceEden your answer helped me, but I couldn't find the documentation. Can you please share where can I find more details about twitter image sizes. I want to retrieve the profile images in large size, too.